# Android, Is it poosible to use system timer as broadcast receiver?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

In my application I need to refresh my data in each 5s or 10s or 1 minute, according to my user preference.

I can create thread and use timer class but i want to know is there any other way? for example timer of system sends flag (broadcast something) and i get it in application (in order to refresh my data)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to refresh the data every serval seconds, you can setup a [Hanlder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) to do this. However, this requires your activity keeps running.

If you want to do something at a specific time, like an Alarm. You can use the [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html). This would lauch your activity or other components even it is not running now.

If you just want to moniter the change in the system time. Well, there is a Intent [ACTION_TIME_TICK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_TIME_TICK) . You can register a BroadcastReceiver to listent to it and implement your own code when the systemt brocasts it. However, the "TICK" interval is "One Minute" only and can not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

[AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) is what you are looking for. It can be used to set up periodic events that are delivered via a [PendingIntent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html) (which can be turned into an Intent broadcast).

I would be wary checking for new data on such a regular interval unless the device is always connected to a power source, especially if you are making the check over a network. With that small a poll interval going to the nework the battery will be flat in hours.